# File pointer becomes NULL on second iteration of while loop

Tags: c, loops, pointers, text-files

I'm coding a text game where the user input is compared to the list of commands available in a text file I have.

It works fine, but I want it to loop so the user can do multiple actions before entering the command which breaks the loop and moves the program along. Unfortunately my file pointer becomes `NULL` on the second iteration of the loop and thus breaks out of the program entirely.

Indentation is a bit confusing, for which I apologize:

```
    int mansionOutside(void)
    {
        int stop = 1; //control variable for while, yeah I know its a shit method of doing it, sue me
        char choice[25]; //Variable to store user input
        char word_match[15] = "outside"; //counter and .txt will be strcat to it
        char text_line[73]; //size of line for txt files
        char line1[25]; //takes current line being read from file
        char temp[2]; //character and '\0' so counter can be made into a string and strcat into word_match
        int counter = 1; //counts number of lines
        int stop2 = 1;
        while (stop2 == 1)
        {
            FILE *fptr;
            fptr = fopen("mansion_commands.txt", "r"); //opens file
            int lookdoor_counter = 0;
            printf("%p\n", fptr);
            if (fptr == NULL)
            {
                perror("ERROR!"); //Error handling for not opening file
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else
            {
                while (stop == 1)
                {   
                    puts(""); //newline, as the previous function ends in a text line
                    fgets(choice, sizeof choice, stdin); //store input in choice with buffer overflow protection

                    while (fgets(line1, 25, fptr) != NULL) //reads until newline
                    {
                        if (strcmp(line1, choice) == 0) //if choice is equal to the current line
                        {
                            //printf("%s\n", line1); //debugging print
                            if (strcmp(line1, "LOOK door") == 0)
                            {
                                lookdoor_counter++; //so that on entering LOOK door a second time, a different
                        //message will appear
                            }
                        stop = 0; // will exit from loop
                        break; //break ensures we can use the current counter value for later
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter++;
                        //printf("%s + %s\n", line1, choice); //debugging
                    }
                }

            if  (stop == 1)
            {
                printf("I dont understand\n"); 
                //printf("%d\n", counter);
                //printf("%s\n", line1);
                //printf("%s\n", choice);
                counter = 1; //counter is reset to be able to try again
                rewind(fptr);
            }
        }
        fclose(fptr);
        if (lookdoor_counter == 2)
        {
            counter += 1;
        }
        counter = counter + '0'; //convert counter digit to its equivalent ascii
        temp[0] = counter; 
        temp[1] = '\0'; //temp becomes a string with counter and EOF char
        //printf("%c\n", counter);

        strncat(word_match, temp , 1); //wordmatch gets counter strncat to it
        strcat(word_match, ".txt"); /*If the string is found on the second line
        word_match will be (outside2.txt), which contains the appropriate 
        message for that user command*/
        //printf("%s\n", word_match); //debugging
        if (strcmp(word_match, "outside4.txt") == 0)
        {
            stop2 = 0;
        }
        fptr = fopen(word_match, "r"); //we open word_match file
        if (fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR!\n"); //error handling
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("Debugging : File opened Successfully\n");

            while (fgets (text_line, 72, fptr) != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s", text_line); // Prints every Line with a 2 sec delay
                //delay(2);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
return 1;
```

}

Comment: Use a step by step debuger and check the error code

Comment: Hi, the use of your stop vars is a bit confusing for me, but if you want the user to continue with his input you'd should set the stop var back to 1 sometimes.

Comment: What is `rewind(fptr);` doing?

Comment: Well turns out the problem was pretty simple, indeed it was due to bad indentation not making it clear when loops started or ended, am breaking the whole thing down into smaller functions,  although it now works as intended.

Comment: @AlbertoDarias So it was an important lesson now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fptr = fopen("mansion_commands.txt", "r"); //opens file
if (!fptr)perror("fopen");
```

add this if condition and look that for the what is the actual error. Maybe you do not have permission on the fs or the path is not true, etc...